# Minimize interpolation error for sin$(x)$ on $[0,\pi]$

Tags: polynomials, interpolation

The interpolation error $R(x) = f(x) - L(x)$ of the interpolation polynom $L$ is given for $x_1 \le x \le x_n$ by

$$R(x) = {f^{n}(\xi) \over n!} \prod_{i=1}^n (x - x_i)$$ where $x_1 < \xi < x_n $ if $x_i$ is sorted in a ascending order. Find (two) sampling points $x_i$ such that sin$( x)$ is on $[0, \pi]$ interpolated with a first-degree polynomial as precise as possible (w.r.p. to the maximum-norm).

My approach was basically to minimize $$R(x) = {-sin(\xi) \over 2} (x-x_1)(x-x_2)$$ (ignoring the first term at first). I received that $f(x) = (x-x_1)(x-x_2)$ has a local minimum at $x_0 = {x_1 + x_2 \over 2}$. Nevertheless $x_1=0$ and $x_2 = \pi$ on the boundary should also be taken into consideration.

I don't see right know how I can continue from that.

Comment: Don't you want to minimize $\int_0^\pi \left(R(x)\right)^2dx$ ?

Comment: How do you come to that?

Comment: $R(x)$ is the interpolation error function, so $R(a)$ is the error at a single point.  You want to minimize the error over a whole interval of interest, right?  Integrating the error over the interval of interest gives you a metric to minimize.  The squaring keeps the contributions to the error metric positive over the whole interval.  I don't quite know what you mean by maximum norm.

Comment: As Ian stated, $\xi$ depends on $x$ so I am not sure how I can solve that.

Comment: @AndyWalls No, this is the minimax problem, not the least squares problem. The minimax problem is in general far more difficult, which is why we usually don't solve it directly. Instead we usually either solve some interpolation problem on a node set that hopefully gives a good approximation to the minimax solution, or we use a "global metric" like least squares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea in general fails because $\xi$ is a function of $x$.

The equioscillation theorem tells you that the minimizer is uniquely characterized by the requirement that there be three points a,b,c where the error is the same value but alternating in sign. By the symmetry this can be achieved by simply taking p to be 1/2, so that the requirement is satisfied by $0,\pi/2,\pi$.

Comment: Which polynomial do I get?

Comment: @Pazu I actually did say that already...

Comment: So you basically meant the constant polynomial p = 1/2? Not sure if this what I am looking for since I need a first-degree polynomial given by two points $x_i$ .

Comment: @Pazu It is a polynomial of degree at most $1$ which can be given as an interpolation polynomial for $\sin$ with two points. It is also the minimax polynomial among polynomials of degree at most $1$ for $\sin$ on this interval.

Comment: I didn't plan to use this (powerful) theorem but it worked out perfectly. Just two last notes: $\sigma = 1$ and the two points I was looking for were $x_0 = { \pi \over 6} $ and $ x_1 = {5 \pi \over 6}$.